# Query not returning desired ordered result

Tags: mysql, sql

**Query Sentence**

```
select NC.Notice_comment_id, 
       N.Notice_subject, 
       NC.Notice_comment_writer_nickname,
       NC.Notice_comment_content, 
       NC.Notice_comment_register_date, 
       NC.admin_read_check,
       NC.Member_id, 
       NC.Notice_num
  from notice_comment NC 
       inner join notice N
           on NC.Notice_num = N.Notice_num;
 where NC.admin_read_check = 'F';
 order by NC.Notice_comment_id desc;
```

**Sample Result**

```
Notice_comment_id    Notice_subject        Notice_comment_writer_nickname
              1      'hello'               'hello'
              2      'hello'               'hello'
              3      'hello'               'hello'
              4      'hello'               'hello'
              5      'hello'               'hello'
              6      'hello'               'hello'
              7      'hello'               'hello'
```

**Why are you doing this?**

Comment: how can we know its not ordering ? please provide sample data .

Comment: Why are we doing what? Reading your question? Because you've asked

Comment: It's not ordering because you have `;` at the wrong places, remove the first two `;` and see what happens.

Comment: is this your query or somebody's else ? If so you might wanna consider asking him first.

Comment: Thank you to those who gave help. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove all `;`

like that

```
SELECT NC.Notice_comment_id, N.Notice_subject, NC.Notice_comment_writer_nickname,
    NC.Notice_comment_content, NC.Notice_comment_register_date, NC.admin_read_check,
   NC.Member_id, NC.Notice_num
 FROM notice_comment NC 
 inner JOIN notice N
 ON NC.Notice_num = N.Notice_num
 WHERE NC.admin_read_check = 'F'
 ORDER BY NC.Notice_comment_id desc
```

Comment: Thank you to those who gave help. ^_^

Comment: @user3427989 if this solved your problem , then make sure to accept this answer as solved.